# discord.py how to make a JSON file work on Heroku

Tags: discord.py

When I host the bot using Heroku it no longer calculates the JSON files (even if it makes them work they do not appear) and when I restart it is as if nothing had happened and reset everything.
How can I do?

Comment: Heroku doesn't have persistent storage. Every time you redeploy it's reset (except for the runtime and the dependencies). Consider using a Database to store your data. [npoint](https://www.npoint.io/) offers JSON storage.

Comment: any videos that can help me?

Comment: Found a [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y9DzfPJsP2s).

Comment: is it possible to have a video for JSON files?

Comment: I'd say go through a tutorial and try things out. You'll have it figured  out faster than you think.

Comment: I kindly ask ...

Answer (score 0):

Heroku does not store changes made to files. Heroku dynos restart every once in a while, and that is when data is lost; redeploying the app can also cause the data to be lost. Using a third-party database, such as [MongoDB](https://mongodb.com) is recommended.

Comment: always using heroku as host?

Comment: What do you mean?